# Set state from props change in react functional component?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-props, react-functional-component, react-state

I have simple react functional component looks like this following code

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Test
        children={
          <React.Fragment>
            <label>Name: </label>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setData(e)} /> 
          </React.Fragment>
        }
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export function Test({ children }) {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  return (
    <>
      <div>{children && children}</div>
      <div>{data}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

My question is how to update `data` state inside `Test` Component when onChange event triggered?
Here is the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/dreamy-mccarthy-ee63r?file=/src/App.js)

Hopefully anyone can help me..
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use use `render props` technique for this and you can can keep your pattern intact if you do not prefer major refactoring.

Working Demo - https://codesandbox.io/s/flamboyant-monad-hw2lu?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export function Child(props) {
  const { setData } = props;
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <label>Name: </label>
      <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setData(e.target.value)} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Test
        render={(props) => {
          const { setData } = props;
          return <Child setData={setData} />;
        }}
      ></Test>
    </div>
  );
}

export function Test(props) {
  const [data, setData] = useState("");
  const { render } = props;
  return (
    <>
      <div>{render({ setData })}</div>
      <div>{data}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much Diwakar. It's totally work as what I want.

Answer (score 1):

You dont have to send children that way. React has a specific way of handling children which is more easier to do and maintain. In your case you just have to lift you state up and send the `state` and `callback` as props.

```js
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
 const [data, setData] = React.useState('')
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <Test data={data}>
         <> // shorthand for ReactFragment
            <label>Name: </label>
            <input type="text" onChange={(e) => setData(e.target.value)} value={data}/> 
         </>
      </Test>
    </div>
  );
}

export function Test({ data, children }) {
  return (
    <>
      <div>{children && children}</div>
      <div>{data}</div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Comment: I don't wanna create another state in parent component. Thanks you Rey

Comment: Oh didn't realized that.